# Sliced rendering with OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm looking to render to a high resolution FBO at runtime. The tough part is I cannot stall/slow down the rendering of the display while rendering to the FBO.

I'm thinking I should render parts of the FBO with glScissor each renderframe. However if I render an object this way, lots of vertices will be cycled through that won't be drawn, which seems slow.

My current solution in mind is to cut up the model into smaller parts, each part dedicated to a glScissor use.

This is quite a complex process though, since it means I have to generate a pipeline for the models so that they will be cut up appropriately.

Is there an easier way than I'm thinking of? Or should I continue on this route?

Comment: How large is your FBO?

Comment: FBO will be 2k x 2k at guess.

Comment: I don't think it is that large. If you don't have extra fancy shaders, I see no problem in rendering that all at once.

Comment: Make a new thread, make a new context, make the new context current in the new thread, do whatever rendering you want and insert a fence or glFinish(). Your OGL driver should automatically loadbalance between the two contexts, one rendering to your screen,  the other to the FBO. If you need more fine-grained load balancing (say 30-70), you might need a different setup. This only works if you don't need the big FBO displayed in the render window.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The rendering is done on mobile, so it actually is quite large. Plus, the model has a lot of polygons.

Comment: @HenkDeBoer I would need more fine grained load balancing indeed. Probably 10-90. Should I stick to my current idea of handling this?

Comment: @HenkDeBoer I don't need to render the same FBO in the other context, but context sharing might work iffy on Android, not sure.

Comment: Ah yeah, android, that might make that difficult. I don't know. Trouble with your current approach is: You will be heavily bottlenecked by vertex throughput. So even though you only render tiny pieces of the FBO each frame, you still waste a lot of time calculating vertex positions (assuming there are a lot of vertices). If you can get context sharing to work, you could still do some load balancing by drawing only a few models to the FBO at a time, but you'll need to keep track of how much time you are spending, and adjust future draw calls accordingly.

Comment: Without performance testing we can't tell you what makes sense.  For all we know, the image you want to render is fill-rate limited, and all you need to do is use scissor.  But, for all we know, the vertex shader is the slow part, and you'll need to chop it up or cache the results with transform feedback.  You'll need to do some measurements first if you want us to give you useful advice on how to approach it.

Comment: @HenkDeBoer That's why I thought to to slice the model up. Since the model is in a static position and the camera as well, I can make a sliced model, with each slice of the model being meant for a glScissor'ed render. That would significantly limit the amount of vertices being calculated. The draw calls still increase from 1 per fbo, to 1 for every slice of the fbo however.

Comment: Are you rendering the whole model with a single draw call? Otherwise, couldn't you just make a few draw calls in each step? I think this will be hard to answer in general, without actually testing and measuring it. I also suspect that the performance of various approaches will be highly vendor dependent.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I could use a drawcall for each step. I was contemplating rendering a cut part of the model for each step (sort of like frustrum culling), instead of trying to render the entire model each step, as in my knowledge that leads to a lot of vertices being tested that won't end up drawn anyway. However, there are still multiple draw calls made, so it's not as efficient as could be, but I guess without controlled context sharing it's as good as it gets in this scenario. But if anyone has a better idea, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using multiple indexbuffers for the same vertexbuffer. The indexbuffers contain slices to be rendered. Alternatively it might be beneficial to use shared contexts and not use slices, but for sake of portability and stability I do it this way.